# Simple C Program Logic Error + Pointer Misunderstanding

Tags: c, pointers

I need some quick help with this C program I am trying to get running. It compiles and runs but it has a logic error somewhere. When the distance is displayed, it displays some large number (all the same, like 2117900), rather than the correct ones. Without a debugger, I have no idea how to find the error. I am fluent in C# and Java but C is coming as bit of a struggle to me. Hopefully someone can find the logic error. Also, any tips from my code you see, especially about pointers, would be greatly appreciated!

point.c file:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "point.h"
#include <math.h>

/*
 * Update *p by increasing p->x by x and 
 * p->y by y
 */
void point_translate(Point *p, double x, double y)
{
    p = point_set(p,(point_getX(p)+x),(point_getY(p)+y));
}

/*
 * Return the distance from p1 to p2
 */
double point_distance(const Point *p1, const Point *p2)
{
    double temp1 = (point_getX(p1) - point_getX(p2));
    double temp2 = (point_getY(p1) - point_getY(p2));
    double temp3 = (temp1*temp1)+(temp2*temp2);
    double dist = sqrt(temp3);
    return dist;
}
```

point.h file:

```
#include <math.h>
#ifndef _POINT_H_
#define _POINT_H_
/*
 * Simplistic definition of point and operations on
 * a point for 2D double-precision space.
 */

typedef struct PointStruct 
{
  double x;
  double y;
} Point;

void point_translate(Point *p, double x, double y);
double point_distance(const Point *p1, const Point *p2);

static inline double point_getX(const Point *p)
{
  return p->x;
}
static inline double point_getY(const Point *p)
{
  return p->y;
}
static inline Point *point_set(Point *p, double x, double y)
{
  p->x = x; 
  p->y = y; 
  return p;
}

#endif
```

testPoint.c file:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#include "point.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
  Point p1;
  point_set(&p1, 1.0, 1.0);

  double distance;

  Point *p2 = malloc(sizeof(Point));
  assert(p2);
  point_set(p2, 1.0, 1.0);

  distance = point_distance(&p1, p2);
  printf("The distance is: %d\n",distance);

  point_translate(&p1, 1.0, 0.0);
  distance = point_distance(&p1, p2);
  printf("The distance is: %d\n",distance);

  point_set(&p1, 0.0, 0.0);
  point_set(p2, 3.0, 4.0);
  distance = point_distance(&p1, p2);
  printf("The distance is: %d\n",distance);

  free(p2);
  p2 = NULL;

  printf("OK\n");
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Here's a tip: turn the compiler warnings up to maximum, and fix all the warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `printf` and similar functions, you must be careful to match format specifiers with the correct type of data.  `"%d"` expects an argument of type `int`, but your arguments have type `double`.  `"%g"` is a good default specifier for `double` arguments.